# How do I optimize a pandas apply lambda that looks at all records?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID   YEAR   AMOUNT
1 |  2001 | 4340
1 |  2002 | 5460
1 |  2004 | 1245
1 |  2006 | 6000
2 |  2003 | 5000
2 |  2006 | 3059
....
```

I would like to add a column that computes the highest amount thus far, as in:

```
ID   YEAR   AMOUNT  AMT_MAX
1 |  2001 | 4340  | 4340
1 |  2002 | 5460  | 5460
1 |  2004 | 1245  | 5460
1 |  2006 | 6000  | 6000
2 |  2003 | 5000  | 5000
2 |  2006 | 3059  | 3059
....
```

I wrote this statement to do that:

```
df['AMT_MAX'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
    df[(df.ID == x['ID']) & (df.YEAR <= x['YEAR'])]['AMOUNT'].max(), axis=1 )
```

However this is very slow. How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cummax`

```
df['AMT_MAX'] = df.groupby('ID').AMOUNT.cummax()
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. As I understand, cummax applies in order the df is fed, so if the rows are out of order I just add `df.sort('YEAR').groupby...`.